# Determine DataContract type from XElement

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, datacontract

I am using the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace outside of WCF and would like to find out what Type an element represents - is there a name resolver?  I'd really like something along the lines of:

```
Type ResolveName(XmlQualifiedName typeName);
```

I see that there's something similar in the internal workings of WCF, but I can't seem to find a public one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the point of contract-based serialization ala DataContractSerialization is that it isn't tied to specific types (note: NetDataContractSerializer doesn't share this). As such, there could be zero, one, or many candidate types. Which would it choose?

So no; AFAIK that is fundamentally not possible. You *could* perhaps use reflection over all types in all loaded assemblies, looking for [DataContract] and apply he tests manually, of course.

Normally you have existing Type information (either the root type or the current type), so you only have a small set of candidate types (KnownType etc) to consider.

Comment: Hmm, that's fair - I wouldn't mind it giving me a list of candidate types, even, or accepting a list of "known types", just like the `DataContractSerializer` does.  The main point is that I don't want to deserialize it now, but I want to know what would be loaded if I did.  (Lazy-loading stuff.)  I'm working on a solution that uses Reflection (ugh) and the internal `DataContract` class.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Well, I'm expecting quite a large number (possibly hundreds of thousands) of these objects in the application I'm working on, and I'll be simply storing the path to the object (serialized to harddrive, rather than as a WCF contract) since I expect the application to only work with a smaller (say, hundreds) subset at a time.  We're using DataContract serialization so that XPath can be used to analyze the file by external tools and it saves learning/writing a new serializer.

Comment: @Matt so I can't interest you in a different serializer, then :) I suspect, however, that your scenario is technically more difficult than it seems. The same *element* name can, in the XML, refer to different types in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks, Marc - yeah, I'm aware that it can refer to different types (which is part of the reason why I am using the namespace+name rather than explicitly putting in assembly-qualified type names) - I'll post my reflection-based sample as soon as I'm done with it.  Thanks for hearing me out!

Answer (score 1):

As I still thought I need this functionality, I've gone and written a class to get the information out.  I've used Impromptu-Interface in order to speed up the reflection bits, but this entire process irks me.

```
public class DataContractNameResolver
{
    private Type TypeOfDataContract = null;
    private Dictionary<System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName, Type> xmlNames = new Dictionary<System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName, Type>();

    internal void PrecacheBaseTypes(IEnumberable<Type> types)
    {
        if (TypeOfDataContract == null)
        {
            TypeOfDataContract = Type.GetType("System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
        }

        lock (xmlNames)
        {
            var remaining = new Queue<Type>(types.Except(xmlNames.Values));

            while (remaining.Count > 0)
            {
                Type next = remaining.Dequeue();

                var dc = Impromptu.InvokeMember(TypeOfDataContract.WithStaticContext(), "GetDataContract", next);
                IDataContract result = Impromptu.ActLike<IDataContract>(dc);

                xmlNames.Add(new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName(result.Name.Value, result.Namespace.Value), next);
            }
        }
    }

    public Type ResolveName(System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeName)
    {
        if (xmlNames.ContainsKey(typeName))
        {
            return xmlNames[typeName];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use of this class would be something like:

```
var nameResolver = new DataContractNameResolver();
nameResolver.PrecacheBaseTypes(new[] { typeof(SampleOne), typeof(SampleTwo) });
var resultType = nameResolver.ResolveName(...);
```